# Content-type columns not showing

Tags: content-type

I have created a SharePoint project in Visual Studio 2010 using the SharePoint 2010 empty project template and have added a ContentType project item and populated the generated elements.xml with the required fields. When I press  to deploy and debug the solution/feature to my SharePoint 2010 Team site, I can see the new site columns as well as the custom content type. However, when I click on the content type, only two fields are listed under the content type columns (Title, Date Logged). The other fields are missing even though I can see them when I goto Site Columns. Could someone please help me get my columns show up.

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Date Logged -->
  <Field ID="{F04AAD0C-56DC-4EFE-AA5E-1C984F352518}"
     Name="DateLogged"
     DisplayName="Date Logged"
     Type="DateTime"
     Required="TRUE"
     Group="Shingi Columns" />
  <!-- Date Received -->
  <Field ID="{4347C6B1-8C38-4859-83F5-43E962440868}"
     Name="DateReceived"
     DisplayName="Date Received"
     Type="DateTime"
     Required="TRUE"
     Group="Shingi Columns" />
  <!-- Action -->
  <Field ID="{7A476F0E-8719-441A-BB9F-B52F2040022C}"
     Name="Action"
     DisplayName="Action"
     Required="TRUE"
     Type="Choice"
     Group="Shingi Columns">
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>Weekend Meeting</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>Information</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>File</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
</Field>
<!-- Date Action Required -->
<Field ID="{34773B19-7443-47E2-9BEB-3A4B7F13B645}"
     Name="DateActionRequired"
     DisplayName="Date Action Required"
     Type="DateTime"
     Required="FALSE"
     Group="Shingi Columns" />
<!-- Action Comment -->
<Field ID="{D2AC4E9B-C91F-4622-A8C9-0E305E6CD8E5}"
     Name="ActionComment"
     DisplayName="Action Comment"
     Required="FALSE"
     Type="Text"
     Mult="FALSE"
     Group="Shingi Columns"/>
<!-- Date Action Completed -->
<Field ID="{67D1F5B1-B45C-448E-8CA5-75F043258D7E}"
     Name="DateActionCompleted"
     DisplayName="Date Action Completed"
     Type="DateTime"
     Required="FALSE"
     Group="Shingi Columns"/>
<!-- Document Direction -->
<Field ID="{9C299634-18DF-41C2-BEA9-C37AC7942589}"
     Name="DocumentDirection"
     DisplayName="Document Direction"
     Type ="Choice"
     Required="TRUE"
     Group="Shingi Columns">
  <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>Inward</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Outward</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>
<!-- Forwarded to -->
<Field ID="{C097876C-2C59-4306-909E-5D8858A913B3}"
     Name="ForwardedTo"
     DisplayName="Forwarded To"
     Type ="Choice"
     Required="TRUE"
     Group="Shingi Columns">
  <CHOICES>
    <CHOICE>Manager One</CHOICE>
    <CHOICE>Manager Two</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
</Field>

<!-- Parent ContentType: Item (0x01) -->
<ContentType ID="0x0100d6ad22b896a147aa8a0103451e7fc71b"
           Name="Shingi Correspondence"
           Group="Shingi Correspondence Content Types"
           Description="My Correspondence Content Type"
           Inherits="TRUE"
           Version="0">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef ID="{F04AAD0C-56DC-4EFE-AA5E-1C984F352518}" Name="DateLogged" />
    <!-- Date Received -->
    <FieldRef ID="{4347C6B1-8C38-4859-83F5-43E962440868}" Name="DateReceived" />
    <!-- Action -->
    <FieldRef ID="{7A476F0E-8719-441A-BB9F-B52F2040022C}" Name="Action" />
    <!-- Date Action Required -->
    <FieldRef ID="{34773B19-7443-47E2-9BEB-3A4B7F13B645}" Name="DateActionRequired" />
    <!-- Action Comment -->
    <FieldRef ID="{D2AC4E9B-C91F-4622-A8C9-0E305E6CD8E5}" Name="ActionComment" />
    <!-- Date Action Completed -->
    <FieldRef ID="{67D1F5B1-B45C-448E-8CA5-75F043258D7E}" Name="DateActionCompleted" />
    <!-- Document Direction -->
    <FieldRef ID="{9C299634-18DF-41C2-BEA9-C37AC7942589}" Name="DocumentDirection" />
    <!-- Forwarded To -->
    <FieldRef ID="{C097876C-2C59-4306-909E-5D8858A913B3}" Name="ForwardedTo" />
  </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comments inside your field and field refs. The XML parser is... well...lets just say lacking! It doesnt like comments for certain fields. I see this behaviour for several kind of artifacts, including the above mentioned.

Annoying, since it makes perfect sense to describe what you do.